# I can't install openssl libraries and openssl commands don't work, but openssl is installed

Tags: 20.04, openssl

That's the output for "openssl version":

```
Command 'openssl' not found, did you mean:

  command 'openssn' from deb openssn (1.4-3build1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Here's what "sudo install libssl-dev" returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl-dev' has no installation candidate
```

And when I trying to install OpenSSL with "sudo apt install openssl"

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/openssl version` work? if not, you've probably manually deleted the binary and will need to reinstall the package (`sudo apt install --reinstall openssl`)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

````
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

add deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main

sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev

sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev```
````

Comment: Thanks! It seems to help with installing library. But I am still don't know what to do with my openssl. It seems to be installed, but it doesn't work. I thought by deciding problem with it I would be able to install libssl-dev, but I had mistaken, it's two different problems.

Comment: What do you mean by saying it doesn't work? does it show any error? or you can't establish the connection? can you give me a little bit more info so I can help you?